# Angular Storybook - Is there a way to generate .stories.ts files automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm looking to generate a `.stories.ts` file inside a component folder once we have run `ng g component my-component`.

The final result should look somehting like this:

```
my-component

  -my-component.component.html

   .

   .

   .

  -my-component.stories.ts
```

What I've found so far is a [PR](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3995) that seems to be resolved about using angular with storybook, but i can't find something that explicitly tells how i can do this

The other solution i came across is creating the sript that generates this extra file by myself so that i can run somehting like:
`ng g component my-component && node generate-story-file.js my-component`

Does anyone know if there is another solution?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom schematic in Angular and while creating the component call it.

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/schematics

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It looks like this article has all answers)
https://mihalcan.medium.com/override-default-angular-schematics-7717fad2d098